# SQL select query order by day and month

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's pretend today is the 3rd of February.

And I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE devotion
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  date timestamp without time zone
}
```

And I have 4 records:

```
id date
1  2013-01-01
2  2013-02-02
3  2013-03-03
4  2013-04-04
```

I want to build a select query that would return all records in the following order (ordered by date, but upcoming dates first, passed dates appended to the end of the list) :

```
id date
3  2013-03-03 (upcoming dates first)
4  2013-04-04
1  2013-01-01 (passed dates appended to the end of the list)
2  2013-02-02
```

All records have the same year. In fact, year is not important, only day and month are. If you can suggest a better structure, you are very welcome.

Comment: Probably using a union of two queries with specific sort orders and where clauses

Comment: Is it too simple to think you need an order by `desc`...

Comment: @Lamak thanks. Both Futures & Past dates `ASC`...interesting. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order by case when date1 > now() then 0 else 1 end case, date1`

will give order of 3,4,1,2

Comment: Can you add select clause as well please.

Comment: Wow, this really works, just adding a reference to the docs here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

```
ORDER BY (date1 < now()), date1
```

You can just order by the boolean value of the expression `(date1 < now())`.
`FALSE` sorts before `TRUE` sorts before `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Ofcourse above answer is good enough. You can't assume today is Feb 3rd since we are taking `Now()` which stand for `Feb 2nd`. So I used demo data `2013-02-01`. And this answer is mainly depending on your `ID`. To say that ID is sequential so is the date. **Anyone is free to comment on the *dodgy part* of this logic**..

[MYSQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f926/4)

```
select id, `date`,
case when `date` > Date_Format(Now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
then id-3
else id+2 end as x
from demo
order by x asc
;

| ID |                            DATE | X |
--------------------------------------------
|  3 |    March, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 0 |
|  4 |    April, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 1 |
|  1 |  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 3 |
|  2 | February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were on MySQL i'd say just use `RIGHT`, but the below should work on psql:

```
SELECT * FROM devotion ORDER BY substring(to_char( date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from char_length(to_char( date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - 5)
```