# Crosstab transpose query request

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Using Postgres 9.3.4, I've got this table:

```
create table tbl1(country_code text, metric1 int, metric2 int, metric3 int);
insert into tbl1 values('us', 10, 20, 30);
insert into tbl1 values('uk', 11, 21, 31);
insert into tbl1 values('fr', 12, 22, 32);
```

I need a crosstab query to convert it to this:

```
create table tbl1(metric text, us int, uk int, fr int);
insert into tbl1 values('metric1', 10, 11, 12);
insert into tbl1 values('metric2', 20, 21, 22);
insert into tbl1 values('metric3', 30, 31, 32);
```

As an added bonus, I'd love a rollup:

```
create table tbl1(metric text, total int, us int, uk int, fr int);
insert into tbl1 values('metric1', 33, 10, 11, 12);
insert into tbl1 values('metric2', 63, 20, 21, 22);
insert into tbl1 values('metric3', 93, 30, 31, 32);
```

I'm done staring at the crosstab spec, I have it written with case statements but it's mad unruly and long, so can someone who's fluent in crosstab please whip up a quick query so I can move on?

Comment: DO you have more countries? or just these three?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14087244/460557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special difficulty is that your data is not ready for cross tabulation. You need data in the form *row_name*, *category*, *value*. You can get that with a `UNION` query:

```sql
SELECT 'metric1' AS metric, country_code, metric1 FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'metric2' AS metric, country_code, metric2 FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'metric3' AS metric, country_code, metric3 FROM tbl1
ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC;
```

But a smart `LATERAL` query only needs a single table scan and will be faster:

```sql
SELECT x.metric, t.country_code, x.val
FROM   tbl1 t
     , LATERAL (VALUES
         ('metric1', metric1)
       , ('metric2', metric2)
       , ('metric3', metric3)
       ) x(metric, val)
ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC;
```

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102743/3684)

Using the simple form of `crosstab()` with 1 parameter with this query as input:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT x.metric, t.country_code, x.val
   FROM   tbl1 t
   , LATERAL (
      VALUES
        ('metric1', metric1)
      , ('metric2', metric2)
      , ('metric3', metric3)
      ) x(metric, val)
   ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC
   $$
   ) AS ct (metric text, us int, uk int, fr int);
```

List country names in alphabetically descending order (like in your demo).
This also assumes all metrics are defined `NOT NULL`.

If one or both are not the case, use the 2-parameter form instead:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

#### Add "rollup"

I.e. totals per metric:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT x.metric, t.country_code, x.val
   FROM  (
      TABLE tbl1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'zzz_total', sum(metric1)::int, sum(metric2)::int, sum(metric3)::int  -- etc.
      FROM tbl1
      ) t
   , LATERAL (
      VALUES
        ('metric1', metric1)
      , ('metric2', metric2)
      , ('metric3', metric3)
      ) x(metric, val)
   ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC
   $$
   ) AS ct (metric text, total int, us int, uk int, fr int);
```

`'zzz_total'` is an arbitrary label, that must sort last alphabetically (or you need the 2-parameter form of `crosstab()`).

If you have *lots* of metrics columns, you might want to build the query string dynamically. Related:

- [How to perform the same aggregation on every column, without listing the columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760230/how-to-perform-the-same-aggregation-on-every-column-without-listing-the-columns/13766567#13766567)
- [Executing queries dynamically in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616126/executing-queries-dynamically-in-pl-pgsql/29617481#29617481)

Also note that the upcoming Postgres 9.5 (currently beta) introduces a dedicated [SQL clause for `ROLLUP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).
Related:

- [Spatial query on large table with multiple self joins performing slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466837/spatial-query-on-large-table-with-multiple-self-joins-performing-slow/31509453#31509453)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me and giving a very concise solution.  How would I add the rollup value to that?  Would I need to pre-calculate that by adding a country_code called total to the source data before doing the crosstab?